# How to fix func is ambiguous in the namespace 'system' compiler error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a method that looks like this :

```
Function ExecuteAndLogError(Of TResult)(ByVal code As Func(Of TResult), _
                                        ByVal sql As String, _
                                        Optional ByVal parameters As SqlParameterCollection = Nothing) As TResult
End Function
```

I am getting this compiler error :

> 'Func' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System'.

This is the line that has the problem

`Func(Of TResult)`

These are my references for the website

[image: These are my references]

This is what I'm importing

- Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Imports System.Data.SqlClient
- Imports System.Data
- Imports System.Diagnostics
- Imports System.Linq

Did I forget to import something or add a reference to something?

**More Info**

I recently upgrade my website from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Happen to have created or imported a class or struct named `Func` ?

Comment: Func is System.Func, you don't have an import for System

Comment: @asawyer To the best of my knowledge I haven't. I just did a search for `Func(` with no results.

Comment: @Splash-X that's what I thought. I just converted this project from 2005 to 2008, then I added a new class with the method from above, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Either Import System or change Func to System.Func

Comment: @Splash-X I just did both and I still get the same error.

Comment: What framework is your target application? Ambiguous means it can't tell them difference between two different methods. It likely could have happened when you updated the project. Some people have noted that a double reference to mscorlib caused similar problems with other things in the System namespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857/why-does-vs-2005-keep-giving-me-the-x-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-y-erro

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5694/discussion-between-guanome-and-splash-x)

Comment: @Splash-X I figured it out, I was referencing NewtonSoft.json, which was referencing a 2.0 version of System, so there were two `Func`s. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix this problem.

I went to the object explorer in Visual Studio and searched for `Func`. I had two references to everything in `System` because I had imported a library, Newtonsoft.Json. Because I had upgraded my website from 2005 to 2008 Newtonsoft was still referencing the 2.0 framework. So, I just deleted my reference to Newtonsoft and that fixed my problem.